# Is there an alternative to mail-notification which supports Hotmail?

Tags: software-recommendation, email, notification

I need a notification applet/daemon for Gnome Shell (on 11.10) that supports both Gmail and Hotmail. I tried mail-notification which is supposed to work with Hotmail, but I get an error and only Gmail works properly; I also tried Mailnag but it does not seem to run at all. Are there any viable alternatives? I know there are some Firefox extensions that can do this but I use a different browser. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you were using Evolution and didn't like Thunderbird either. If that was to be the case maybe you might be interested in Popper: https://launchpad.net/~ralf.hersel/+archive/rhersel-ppa . It incorporates very well with your Ubuntu system.

I haven't tried it myself but those who did said it's very functional.

Comment: I'm using Popper and recommend it if you need to check multiple email accounts that are POP3 or IMAP